# How to put partial command in command bar?

Tags: command-line, shell

I am trying to do something like this, from a function:

```
nmap <F5> :!python %
```

Pressing F5 in this case causes the command `:!python %` to be left in the command line. This is preferred for me, because occasionally I may want to add extra command arguments or stuff to the end of the command.

However, I'm not sure how to create this behavior from a vim function. The `execute()` function simply executes the command directly, with no chance of editing, while the `normal` command doesn't seem to work.

```
nmap <F5> :call MyDebugFunction()<cr>

function! MyDebugFunction()
  " This just executes right away with no chance of editing
  execute("python %")
  " Neither of these work
  normal! :!python %
  execute "normal! :!python%"
endfunction
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the *very* rare cases in which `feedkeys()` is actually called for. Doing `:call feedkeys(':!python %')` should work, since `feedkeys` puts stuff directly on vim's input buffer.

Answer (score 6):

> while the normal command doesn't seem to work

normal must always return to Normal. It is considered normal in Vim.

> I am trying to do something like this, from a function

Not really useful for this simple example, but, in general, there are many situations one may want it. Simply make use of `:h map-expr` (or, alternatively, the expression register), like this:

```
nnoremap <expr>F5 MyFunction()

function! MyFunction() abort
    " foo, bar, baz..
    return ":!python %"
endfunction
```